# Advice for securing data with a "light" auth on a public webpage

Tags: security, authentication, encryption

**Requirements**

Display semi-secure data on a public webpage (not behind an auth wall) but provide some semblance of security to that data. The user of this system will receive a piece of paper in the mail that has both a 5-8 digit check number and a 10-digit alphanumeric verification code.

**Proposal**

First, a peremptory declaration, I know the data will never been 100% secure without some sort of formal authentication.

I am proposing to have the user enter 3 pieces of information, a numeric 5-8 digit check number, an EIN number, which I believe is 8-10 numeric digits, then a verification code, which we are proposing to be 10 digits alphanumeric.

We would put a server side control on the page to prevent repeated submissions from a single IP address in a XX minute timespan, or force a captcha, I haven't decided yet.

I have two questions...

1. Is the 10-digit alphanumeric code long enough, and I realize this is a relative answer. I'm looking for a "Is this good enough for not-terribly-secure data?" gut check.
2. Is there a better alternative? We can't expect PGP keys or anything of the sort. All the user of the system gets is a piece of paper in the mail.

Answer (score 1):

A 10 digit alphanumeric code gives you 52 bits of entropy (possible characters is 26 letters + 10 digits, assuming single case), assuming it is generated by a CSPRNG:

```
log2(36^10) = 52
```

As a rough guide, [59 bits would take a determined attacker 457.50 hours](http://ss64.com/docs/security.html) (just over 19 days). However, make this 16 characters and you will have the 80 bits NIST recommend for strong passwords (109,527.95 years to crack). Note these times are maximum, for average simply divide by two.

Sending a password using an out of bound mechanism such as the mail is a good security measure. Make sure the password is stored securely on your system using one way bcrypt hashes.

Comment: Combined with the unknowable numeric check number and the unknowable   9 digit numeric EIN number, can you tell me how to compute the years to crack? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Taking the smallest lengths this would be `log2(10^5)+log2(10^8)+log2(36^10)=95 bits`, so over 56,078,315 years to fully search the keyspace.